# Is "factoral" a legitimate word, or could it be a typo?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, is-it-a-word

I recently encountered the term "factoral" used twice in *The Oxford Handbook of Karl Marx*, without any occurrences of "factorial." Below are the excerpts for reference:

1. "As Georg Plekhanov argued more than a century ago, the problem with the *factoral* approach to social analysis lies not in the attempt to distinguish different aspects of the mediated whole but rather in the tendency to reify these factors such that history is made to stand still."
2. "This multilevel analysis of the role of political and social institutions laid the intellectual basis for later *multifactoral* analyses of capitalist stages."

Given that "factoral" does not appear to be a commonly used term (at least in my experience and according to standard dictionaries), I'm curious whether it might be a typo or if it's an intentional choice of vocabulary within this specific context. To better understand its usage, I also conducted a Google search for "factoral analysis" and found several other instances where it was used in formally published texts. Could "factoral" be an established term in certain academic or theoretical discussions, or should it possibly be "factorial" or another term entirely? I'm particularly interested in understanding if others have come across this term and in what capacity.

Comment: In the second sentence "multifactoral" seems to mean "involving many factors". I've no idea what the translator intended by "factoral".

Comment: The term 'factor analysis' is used in statistics.

Comment: You could say "factor approach" and "multifactor analyses" as another alternative.

Comment: All of Marx's works exist only in translation. He did not write in English.

Comment: These days, factoral and factorial are two different words, just like patatal and palatial. Not that they don't get misused from time to time. Note that the book was published in 2019, and the quoted text appears to be contemporary. I haven't figured out when *factorial* ceased to be used in the sense of *factoral*, but it was well before my time - a century at least.

Comment: I found an entry in the American Mathematical Monthly from 1894 that uses *factorial* wrt factor analysis. I may need to close that date range up a bit. https://www.google.com/search?q=Mathematics+probability+statistics+%22factorial%22&sca_esv=7569b3261be45716&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACQVn093gq4dtPBu-T7ylNJLMF_n6AFHcA:1708874886721&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivq9qE58aEAxUk38kDHWyVCIIQpwV6BAgCEBY&biw=1163&bih=463&dpr=1.65

Comment: I suggest searching Google Books for ["factoral"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22factoral%22&sca_esv=7569b3261be45716&sca_upv=1&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACQVn09-T_ARJ4-eLpW_ceLhzDfLgJNouw%3A1708875605255&ei=VV_bZdKMD9vep84P_bmzmAc&ved=0ahUKEwiSi6rb6caEAxVb78kDHf3cDHMQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22factoral%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIgoiZmFjdG9yYWwiMgcQABiABBgNMgcQABiABBgNMgcQABiABBgNMgcQABiABBgNMgcQABiABBgNMgcQABiABBgNMgcQABiABBgNMgcQABiABBgNMgcQABiABBgNMgcQABiABBgNSMEgUPsNWOIecAB4AJABAJgBXaABkQKqAQEzuAEDyAEA-AEBmAIDoAKeApgDAIgGAZIHATM&sclient=gws-wiz-books) so you can see how it is used.

Comment: 1913 use of  *factorial* published in Nature concerning cotton genetics factors. But instances are getting very thin after 1910. https://www.google.com/books/edition/Nature/ExJLAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Mathematics+probability+statistics+%22factorial%22&pg=PA666&printsec=frontcover

Comment: As far as I can tell, only genetics commonly used *factorial* wrt factors after 1910.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One reason why *factoral* doesn't appear in dictionaries is that the suffix *-al* is productive — it can be added to many root words with a standard meaning:

> used to add the meaning "connected with" to adjectives, or "the action of" to nouns:
>
> > medical (= connected with medicine)
> > approval (= the act of approving)
>
> — [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/al)

That definition isn't particularly helpful here, though (and is arguably wrong, because *medicine* is a noun and can produce *medicinal*). The meaning is a bit nebulous and hard to pin down because *‑al* has been around since Middle English, arriving with the Normans.

However, [OED](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/al_suffix1?tab=meaning_and_use) (paywalled) does a better job:

> Forming adjectives with the sense ‘of or relating to that which is denoted by the first element’, e.g. **abysmal** *adj.,* **global** *adj.,* **meditational** *adj.,* **mucosal** *adj.,* **optimal** *adj.,* **palatal** *adj.,* **rotational** *adj.,* **societal** *adj.*

[Note *palatal,* "of the palate"; not *palatial,* "of a palace", although that has a similar construction.]

*Factoral* simply means "relating to factors" or "using factors". A "factoral approach to social analysis" is using different factors ("different aspects") to analyse society. This meaning is reinforced in the last line, "[reify](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reify) these factors".

It has a very similar meaning to *multifactoral:* "multifactoral analysis" is analysis of or using many factors.

Comment: Can analysis of a society take place without considering the factors involved?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fortunately I have no idea. I'm not a sociologist.